# MSI Afterburner doesn't keep fan speed at 80%

Tags: msi-afterburner

I started mining eth 2 days ago and I tried overclocking my GPU. My problem is that MSI Afterburner keeps dropping the fan speed at 15-25% even if I set it to 80%. Any way I can fix this? [this is what MSI hardware monitor shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEIM7.png)

Comment: The fan speed percentage sets a maximum only. If the temperatures don't require that much it won't reach it. This is the correct design. Nothing to fix.

Comment: But then how can I lower the temperature of the GPU to 60ºC?

Comment: @RaresMihaiIordache you need to set a fan curve so that the fan is running at whatever it needs to run at to maintain 60ºC. This might take some trial and error.